# most easy, reliable, cheap way to deploy this python (workhorse) app with a PHP frontend?

Tags: python, hosting

I am developing a small part of a PHP application with some python code. The python code runs like an **equivalent of a servlet** (listens and responds to HTTP on port 8765) on localhost. The PHP app calls it like:

```
PHP'S_CURL("http://localhost:8765/search?term=electrical+design")
```

The pyth-let is written with the BaseHTTPServer module like:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_GET(self):
      if self.path=="/search":
         self.send_response(200)

         # ....

         self.wfile.write(st)
```

It works on my workstation and my colleague's. I now want to **deploy it in a production environment**, with modifications. The idea in mind is that I should:

1. modify my app to FCGI
2. get an inexpensive VPS account
3. set Apache to use FCGI to spawn and keep alive both the PHP app and the pyth-let.

So it's a localhost app, which **shouldnt be exposed publically**. There should be reliable way to **keep it alive**.  We expect ~800 hits a day before needing an upgrade, so only a single instance need be kept alive.

Is there a feasible way to do this on a popular shared host, rather than a VPS? Am I on the right track with my above-mentioned plan?

---

**Postscipts**
I mentioned "easy, reliable, cheap way"
and by "way" I meant both the development direction as well as a good (cheap) hosting plan that can support it.

Comment: Why not just do it all in Python? There are plenty of good web application frameworks written in Python.

Comment: We have a lot of sunk costs in PHP. The python components are to simplify certain stuff (and introduce certain good practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup/wiki/FlupServers) to serve your python app with fastcgi. I've also used [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html) to deploy python webapps along with supervisor and found that to be a good approach - and even easier to setup.